# Constructing stable equivalences for finite dimensional algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, homological-algebra, computer-algebra

Given a finite dimensional (non-selfinjective) algebra $A$.

> Is there a method (for example using QPA) to construct algebras stable equivalent to $A$?

Such a thing is easily possible for derived equivalences via tilting modules but I have not seen such a method for stable equivalences (that do not come necessarily from derived equivalences).

Special cases such as Nakayama algebras are also welcome. In particular:

> Is it known when two Nakayama algebras are stable equivalent? If not, can this be tested with QPA?

Comment: How do you easily find a tilting module over an arbitrary finite dimensional algebra? I assume that then it is similarly easy to at least construct stable equivalences of Morita type.

Comment: @JulianKuelshammer At least for most algebras it is possible with QPA. For representation-finite algebras QPA can find all tilting modules.

Comment: What is the expanded mame of QPA?

Comment: @MarcoFarinati See https://folk.ntnu.no/oyvinso/QPA/ for the name and more information.

Comment: @Mare, thanks for the link saying  "Quiver Path Algebras"